How to solve tabulations problem in WPF with C#
in C# I use the string.Format() function to get an output like this:

Of course, the problem is caused by the \t in this line:
string.Format("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}...)
I tried various string.Format() settings but couldn't fix the problem.
(Yes, I can train a neural network but I can't line up some strings... ironic!)
How to solve the lining up problem in a better way?

This problem is hardly unique to WPF. But WPF does have several solutions. Have you looked at DataGrid or even just Grid?

What you see is the output printed inside a simple TextBox with the command TxtBoxName.Text = string.Format(...). I don't want to involve complex structures like DataGrid, etc because for what I need to do a TextBox is enough. Is there some solution for my case?

String.PadRight.

"I don't want to involve complex structures like DataGrid, etc because for what I need to do a TextBox is enough" - arguably you need something more than a text box if you had difficulties using it for your problem. why? you have to calculate the correct amount of \t or spaces ( ) (whichever you use to align those) based on your string's length. spaces would give you more consistent result but involves mundane math not as fancy as AI.

the mundane math: textBox1.Text = epochLabel.PadRight(20 - epochLabel.Length) + mseLabel.PadRight(20 - mseLabel.Length) + ....

@BagusTesa not sure if I'm misreading your comment, but PadRight takes the desired total length so you wouldn't subtract the initial length. He just has to decide on the column lengths and then do epochLabel.PadRight(x) + mseLabel.PadRight(x) etc. What DataGrid would do which no string math could is ensure that the columns are wide enough to accomodate any entry and stay aligned.

@EmperorEto oh you are absolutely right. i misread the documentation then.

We don't post images of data outputs here. Only having an image, instead of exact text, makes it much harder to provide a precise answer for you.

PadRight() works like a charm for my needs, thank you.

Tabs aren't great for this. You can get a few values with lengths that are slightly different and throw off the whole table, or run it on a different system with different length tab stops and suddenly everything is weird.
But String.Format() does give you an easy option to fix this, using the padding alignment options insetad of tabs to get fixed-width results:
string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-20}{2}...")

Note the documentation still mentions one important caveat:

If the value of alignment is less than the length of the formatted string, alignment is ignored, and the length of the formatted string is used as the field width.

But as long as your desired width is longer than the inputs, you'll be fine.
